# Customize Twenty Fourteen Theme Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Twenty Fourteen Theme. I would like to ask how do I customize twenty fourteen theme?

1. I would like to change the whole twenty fourteen from black to white. i.e. the header menu, footer and left sidebar I want it to be in white instead of black.
2. I would also like the search bar to be of a different color.
3. I also want my homepage to show "Read More" link instead of full posts. Where do I start?
4. I would like to remove categories from all my pages.

After doing my research online, I see that I need a child theme, which I am very interested to learn. But I am not too sure if I should proceed this way?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a child theme is vital, it keeps your settings even after updating a theme. This is a good template for a [twenty fourteen child theme](http://techdwarf.com/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial/).
After creating your child theme, add these codes to your style.css in your child theme folder.

To change background color of left sidebar,

```
#secondary { 
background: #dcadc5; 
}
```

To change footer background color:

```
.site-footer{ 
background: #00ff42; // change background color
}
```

To remove categories from posts:

```
.tag-links { display: none; }
```

Reference: [Modify Twenty Fourteen Theme WordPress](http://techdwarf.com/customize-twenty-fourteen-theme-wordpress/) . This should also answer some of your other questions.